# Delete XML files from user prompt Python Linux

Tags: python, linux, file, visual-studio-code

I have the following code:

```
 if xmlFileCount > 0:
        
        print("\nALERT:" + str(xmlFileCount) + " EXISTING XML FILES FOUND!\nIf you want to proceed with XML file conversion, type y" )
        decider = input("")
        if decider == "y":
            files = glob.glob('/evtx_logs/**/*.xml', recursive=True)
            for f in files:
                try:
                    os.remove(f)
                except OSError as e:
                    print("Error: %s : %s" %(f, e.strerror))
```

What I am trying to do is get user input and if user input is equal to Y or Yes then delete any XML files found in the evtx_logs directory and its subdirectories, then if No or N entered then terminate the program. I run this code but nothing seems to happen and I am unsure why. I have previously declared the xmlFileCount value.

I am a  recently new programmer so this may be a rookie error. Using Python3, Linux Mint

Comment: use a debugger to see what the value of `decider` is or use `print(repr(decider))` to see if there are extra characters

Comment: Okay I’ll try that!